# What's the difference between Buffer.allocUnsafe() and Buffer.allocUnsafeSlow() in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js

I've read [the docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v13.x/docs/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_allocunsafe_size) on the subject.
It says:

> When using Buffer.allocUnsafe() to allocate new Buffer instances,
> allocations under 4KB are sliced from a single pre-allocated Buffer.
> This allows applications to avoid the garbage collection overhead of
> creating many individually allocated Buffer instances. This approach
> improves both performance and memory usage by eliminating the need to
> track and clean up as many individual ArrayBuffer objects.
>
> However, in the case where a developer may need to retain a small
> chunk of memory from a pool for an indeterminate amount of time, it
> may be appropriate to create an un-pooled Buffer instance using
> Buffer.allocUnsafeSlow() and then copying out the relevant bits.

Also I've found [this explanation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-buffer-allocunsafeslow-method/):

> Buffer.allocUnsafeSlow is different from Buffer.allocUnsafe() method. In
> allocUnsafe() method, if buffer size is less than 4KB than it
> automatically cut out the required buffer from a pre-allocated buffer
> i.e. it does not initialize a new buffer. It saves memory by not
> allocating many small Buffer instances. But if developer need to hold
> on some amount of overhead memory for intermediate amount of time,
> than allocUnsafeSlow() method can be used.

Though it is hard to understand for me. May you explain it more eloquent and detailed with some examples for both, please?